# Applescript to open and save an Indesign Document not working

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I'm currently playing around with creating an applescript droplet that will in the end allow me to drop multiple files to be opened and then saved. This is all I need to do as this updates the old indesign files to CS5 (we have a lot of them).

I'm able to create a droplet that opens multiple indesign files, but im having trouble with them being saved. Here is the script so far:

```
on open these
    tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
        open these
    end tell
end open
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
 save these
end tell
```

At the moment its not executing the "save these" command. Seems like it would be straightforward enough but i'm findin it hard to get information how to tell indesign to save these opened documents that i've dropped in the droplet. I'm probably not using the right "selector" (if I can use that term). So i would like the script to "select" the open documents and these "selected" documents then need to be saved (a simple save command rather than a save as).

And ideally i would like for the script to open the first document and saving it before moving on to the second document and so forth. But that is secondary.

I've also tried this script:

```
on open these
    tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
        open these
    end tell
end open
tell these
    save
end tell
```

Same result here as well. I'm a bit of a beginner on this so I might've overlooked something very basic. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Edit: Typo in the title, whoops!

Comment: Have you checked out Indesign's Scripting Dictionary (just open InDesign with AppleScript Editor) and looked at the save command there?

Comment: @DigiMonk I have yes, I can see a whole wealth of different save commands, but i thought i would only need the basic save command. I believe the problem might lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't just tell indesign to save "thees" you have to talk to each item specifying item and and location format etc for for saving

so you will have to loop through each one

pseudo code here

```
on open these
    repeat with afile in these
        tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
            open afile
            tell document 1
                   save afile to "/location/to/save"
               close afile
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

here is the dictionary instructions for save

save v : Save the document
save specifier
[to alias or text] : Where to save the document. If the document is already saved, a copy is saved at this path, the original file is closed the new copy is opened
[stationery boolean] : Whether to save the file as stationery. Can accept: boolean (Default: FALSE).
[version comments text] : The comment for this version
[force save boolean] : Forcibly save a version. Can accept: boolean (Default: FALSE).
→ document : The saved document

as DigiMonk noted you may just be able to use close by itself

```
on open these
    repeat with afile in these
        tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
            open afile
            tell document 1
                close afile saving yes
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

Comment: Aha, i see. I thought "these" were some sort of selector. only thing is i really do not need to save these documents anywhere else then where they are currently located. Would there be a command that would be similar to the cmd+S action you would normally use if opening and closing these manually?

Comment: you may just try save without a location and it may save back i dont' recall off the top of my head, if your presented with a dialog you may need to turn UI off

Comment: Also you write "afile". Is this a variable?

Comment: YES afile is a variable :)

Comment: "these" is an array, and with "repeat with afile in these" it takes value by value into "afile" to use in the loop.

Comment: aha!, thanks man. I'll give this a go and give a status report later!

Comment: @bestfriendsforever Oh, BTW: there's often an option to "close" a document with saving. In TextEdit the syntax looks like this: "close <object> saving ask/‌no/‌yes]" -- Specifies whether changes should be saved before closing. May be ID has that also.

Comment: ohh good point @DigiMonk that might be much easier i'll add that  :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've given this a go with both your original script and with your input as well @DigiMonk. But in both instances i've gotten the same error message saying "item 1 of {filepath/filename.indd} doesn't understand the <<event CoReclos>> message". I've encountered this earlier in fact but found it hard to find any info on this when i googled it. Anyone heard of this before?